# Postgresql ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables "Persona" (Person) and "Dona" (Female) and I want to alter a third one named "Baptisme" (Baptism), but I'm having some problems.

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE baptismes.Persona (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    nom VARCHAR(255),
    nom_complementari1 VARCHAR(255),
    nom_complementari2 VARCHAR(255),
    nom_complementari3 VARCHAR(255),
    nom_complementari4 VARCHAR(255),
    cognom1 VARCHAR(255),
    cognom2 VARCHAR(255),
    lloc_naixement VARCHAR(255) REFERENCES baptismes.Poblacio(nom),
    data_naixement baptismes.Data,
    alies VARCHAR(255),
    sexe CHAR(1),
    difunt BOOLEAN
);

CREATE TABLE baptismes.Dona (
    cognom_marit_actual VARCHAR(255),
    cognom_marit_anterior VARCHAR(255)
) INHERITS (baptismes.Persona);

CREATE TABLE baptismes.Baptisme (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

Baptisme has more attributes but they doesn't matter here.

What I'm trying to do is:

```
ALTER TABLE baptismes.baptisme
ADD COLUMN mare INTEGER REFERENCES baptismes.Dona(id);
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «dona»
********** Error **********

ERROR: no hay restricción unique que coincida con las columnas dadas en la tabla referida «dona»
SQL state: 42830
```

In english: "there's no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table <>".

I can't understand because Dona gets PK from Persona (id), so it should be `UNIQUE`.

Can somebody help me, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alas, this is a [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-inherit.html) deficiency:

> **5.8.1. Caveats**
>
> A serious limitation of the inheritance feature is that indexes
>   (including unique constraints) and foreign key constraints only apply
>   to single tables, not to their inheritance children. This is true on
>   both the referencing and referenced sides of a foreign key constraint.
>
> - If we declared `cities.name` to be `UNIQUE` or a `PRIMARY KEY`, this would not stop the capitals table from having rows with names
>     duplicating rows in cities. And those duplicate rows would by default
>     show up in queries from cities. In fact, by default capitals would
>     have no unique constraint at all, and so could contain multiple rows
>     with the same name. You could add a unique constraint to capitals, but
>     this would not prevent duplication compared to cities.

So, your problem is that `dona.id` doesn't have a unique constraint.  I think you can declare one in the create table statement -- or by altering the table afterwards.

Comment: But if I declare one in `Dona` table I could have a `dona` with id = 10, for example, and a `person` with same id = 10. Isn't it? And they wouldn't be same person.

Comment: @Lyd . . . Yes, that is exactly one of the "Caveats" in the documentation.